# How to guard Python multiprocessing on Windows from unwanted recursion

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

So, I'm doing this project in which the following steps are ran (necessarily as they are):

- Optimization algorithm program (package O) calls aircraft analysis script as a subprocess;
- Aircraft analysis script (script S) calls an aerodynamics package;
- The aircraft analysis package (lets call it package P) creates several multiprocessing `Process` class instances to parallelize heavy tasks.

On Linux, this works without any issue.

On Windows, however, package P needs a guard stopping the child processes from recursively re-importing their father script S (as in [python multiprocessing on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924018/python-multiprocessing-on-windows)), which leads to an infinitely repeated task execution.

It isn't hard to implement it adding a guard to script S:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    #do stuff, call methods from package P
```

I didn't want my users to have to use that guard in every call to the package, however, so I've added a guard to package P instead. It is implemented as a flag, as in (names edited for simplicity, the package has over 5000 lines):

```
class FirstClass:
    #first method in package P to be executed in script S is FirstClass.__init__
    def __init__(self):
        self.ischild=(multiprocessing.current_process().name != 'MainProcess')
    def some_other_method(self):
        if not self.ischild:
            do_stuff_that_the_package_should_do()
```

So, essentially, package P's funcions and methods are only ran if flag `ischild` is set to False in the first class instantiated by script S.

It works when script S is called from command line, and stops script S from doing anything in a child process as it is re-imported - therefore stopping both redundant tasks and recursive subprocess creation.

When I try to configure optimization package O to run script S as a subprocess, however, this guard stops working, because script S is no longer the main process. Flag `ischild` is, then, set to True even when script S is ran for the first time by package O, because `multiprocessing.current_process().name` is no longer equal to `'MainProcess'` even if the call is not recursive.

Is there any other way I can implement a guard to package P to stop its recursive calls to the main process that would work even if script S is not the main process?

It would be nice if I could identify exactly which package/script summoned the process, with something like:

```
if multiprocessing.father()=='package_P':
    ischild=True #stops execution of function do_stuff_the_package_should_do() when the call is recursive
```

So that no trouble is caused when the calling process is neither the main process (as it wouldn't be if script S is a subprocess of another script or package) nor a child process from package P (recursive call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refactor your code in a way that there's no implicit automagical multiprocessing happening when `S` is imported.

e.g.

```
S/
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
```

where only `S/__main__.py` starts whatever you're doing. You can then run `python -m S` and Python will invoke that main module. Simply importing `S` (or anything from `S`) won't do that.