# Is it possible to pass ndarray type objects in multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'd like to use multiprocessing.Process on a function that takes an ndarray type object in its argument.

```
def func(array):
     do_something_to array
return array
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: this is the code I tried to implement. The function 'noflux' takes a few ndarray type objects and makes changes to the arguments and this is the function I'd like to run on multiple processors.

```
for k in np.arange(0,len(t)-1,1):
    for j, j in enumerate(gridd):        
    
            i = int(j[1])
            j = int(j[0])

            # NO FLUX BOUNDARIES
            if cells[j,i] == 1:

                p1 = mp.Process(target=noflux,args=(j,i,cells,rfu,lfu,ufu,dfu,))
                p2 = mp.Process(target=noflux,args=(j,i,cells,rfh,lfh,ufh,dfh,))
                
                p1.start()
                p2.start()
                
                p1.join()
                p2.join()
```

EDIT 2:
Here are the type of objects I pass to the function...

`j,i` are integers,
`cells` is an ndarray shape (73,87),
`rfu,lfu,ufu,dfu` are also (73,87) ndarrays

the function `noflux` takes these arrays and modifies them but it does not return anything. There's also a function within noflux that is defined and used so maybe this is what's causing the problem?

EDIT 3: Full error message received when running my code. Swapped the real path to file for "PATH"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\PATH", line 418, in <module>
    p1.start()

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did, and received a "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken Pipe" error message. I will edit my question to include the code I tried to use.

Comment: Why do you comment out the last line? and could you show what type of objects you pass into the function?

Comment: Passing ndarrays to a process should not be a problem so something else is probably giving you problems here

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response and that last line wasn't supposed to be commented out but I'm still getting the same error as before. I made an edit in the post to show what kinds of objects I'm passing :)

Comment: could you change the lines `for j, j in enumerate(gridd): i = int(j[1]) j = int(j[0])` to `for l, subgrid in enumerate(gridd): i = int(grid[1]) j = int(grid[0])` and see if that solves anything?

Comment: Trying it I received  ```name 'grid' is not defined ``` and if you meant 'gridd' instead, I should mention that ```gridd.shape = (3142,2)``` and is an array of coordinates used in the loop and so something like ```gridd[1,x]``` would be needed to specify a number from this array. I also tried ```j = int(gridd[l,0])``` and ```i = int(gridd[l,1])``` but again received a broken pipe error.

Comment: Ah sorry,  I meant `for l, subgrid in enumerate(gridd): i = int(subgrid[1]) j = int(subgrid[0])` It's kind of hard to determine what the problem is as your code here does not suggest a problem aside from your use of j for three different variables. Could you post a more elaborate error message?

Comment: Haha, yeah the j thing is a bit stupid I know... I tried again and got the same error message which I will post in an edit.

Comment: Right now I can think of two things happening that you can try. First, since you are on windows could you verify that you implement the issue described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924048/5516057? If that does not work could you try and run it in combination with the solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599967/5516057 and see if an error is raised from your process?